# Any way to fix InDesign element order?

Tags: adobe-indesign

We have an InDesign document that we want to pull the data out of.
The format of each item is as follows:

```
Header
Address
Phone Number
Email
Info paragraph
```

Unfortunately, the people who made the document had not given any consideration to exporting this information, basically treating InDesign like a word processor. They did not use labels for the elements, and did not add the elements in the order they appear.
And since InDesign treats the order elements were added as the actual order, attempting to pull the contents out (by copying a page, by exporting to Word, by exporting to text, pretty much everything I've tried), has resulted in jumbled output like this:

```
Header1
Info Paragraph1
Header2
Address2
Info Paragraph2
Phone2
EMail2
Email1
Phone1
```

Is there some way to refactor the InDesign file so that items that are higher up get pushed back, so they would export out first?

If I could just get these in proper order, then I could write a parser to get most of them exported properly.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Do you export XML from Indesign file and you need to arrange the exported tags in a different order?

Answer (score 0):

I need it in Y axis (top to bottom) order, with left to right for elements with the same Y coordinate.
I had tried having the documentation team export to XML. I also tried opening it in various word processor apps and saving it to a text or HTML format, and they all ended up in an order other than top down.

However, I think I found the answer.
I tried Word again and it seems to have worked this time.
My exact process was opening the PDF in Edge, then saving it and opening the PDF in Word. I did this to remind myself exactly how the scrambled elements looked in it, but to my surprise, it was in the correct order this time.
This solution may only work with Word 365.

Comment: Well, you did not answer my question. If you want to change the order of tags you can just change the order in the structure panel. Another option is to use XSLT when yuo export the document to XML